# H2 with DB2 mode does not recognize keyword 'minute'

Tags: hibernate, db2, h2

I have a project with several integration tests. In order to improve speed of these tests I have decided to use H2 database while they run. But I still want my applciation run with DB2.

I specify to H2 to run in DB2 mode :

```
url: "jdbc:h2:mem:TEST;\
      MODE=DB2;\
      DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;\
      DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;\
      INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SYSIBM\\;\
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1()"
```

One of my tests does not work when I execute this request :

```
update batch set running=current timestamp where id=? and (running is null or running < current timestamp + 1 minute)
```

I have this error message :

```
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE BATCH SET RUNNING=CURRENT TIMESTAMP WHERE ID=?  AND (RUNNING IS NULL OR RUNNING < CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 1 MINUTE[*]) "; expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )";
```

It seems that MINUTE is not recognized. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What about 60 seconds?

Comment: Unfortunatly, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` to compare `running` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? That function appears to be supported by H2 as well as DB2.

Comment: I have already tested it. However I use DB2 9.7 and this feature doesn't exist.

Comment: DB2 9.7 has `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000861.html ) but the syntax is different from H2, and may not be one of the functions H2 can handle in its DB2 compatibility mode.